# error in permission for flashlight app

Tags: android, permissions, flashlight

i managed to run on lolipop devices added permissions on manifest but for marshamellow it didnt worked out the app used to jst freeze n do nothing when tried to turn on flash

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    Parameters params;

    private Context mContext = MainActivity.this;

    private static final int REQUEST = 112;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ImageButton imgbutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);


        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        checkPermission();

        //getCamera();


             imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isFlashOn) {
                    turnOffFlash();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Flash OFF!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_off);

                } else {
                    turnOnFlash();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Flash ON!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
            if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST);
            } else {
                getCamera() ;
            }
        } else {
            getCamera() ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getCamera() ;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to access camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void getCamera() {

        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            }catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        }

    private void turnOnFlash() {

        if(!isFlashOn) {
            if(camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;
        }

    }

    private void turnOffFlash() {

        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(camera!=null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(hasFlash)
            turnOnFlash();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

UPDATE: finally i managed to grand permission for marshamellow devices..permission needed to grand programatically on marshamello n higher so i thats the problem for me which i solved through this community thankyou

Comment: You need to add this permission also.
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;
    private Camera camera;
    private boolean isFlashOn;
    private boolean hasFlash;
    Parameters params;

    private Context mContext = MainActivity.this;

    private static final int REQUEST = 112;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        final ImageButton imgbutton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);


        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        checkPermission();

        //getCamera();


             imgbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isFlashOn) {
                    turnOffFlash();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Flash OFF!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_off);

                } else {
                    turnOnFlash();

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Flash ON!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    imgbutton.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_on);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void checkPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            String[] PERMISSIONS = {android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA};
            if (!hasPermissions(mContext, PERMISSIONS)) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) mContext, PERMISSIONS, REQUEST);
            } else {
                getCamera() ;
            }
        } else {
            getCamera() ;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    getCamera() ;
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "The app was not allowed to access camera", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
            for (String permission : permissions) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    private void getCamera() {

        if (camera == null) {
            try {
                camera = Camera.open();
                params = camera.getParameters();
            }catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

        }

    private void turnOnFlash() {

        if(!isFlashOn) {
            if(camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.startPreview();
            isFlashOn = true;
        }

    }

    private void turnOffFlash() {

        if (isFlashOn) {
            if (camera == null || params == null) {
                return;
            }

            params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
            camera.stopPreview();
            isFlashOn = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        if(camera!=null){
            camera.stopPreview();
            camera.setPreviewCallback(null);
            camera.release();
            camera = null;
        }
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(hasFlash)
            turnOnFlash();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou for your feedback , i have made changes,i updated code but getting enum expected error

Comment: getCamera()  method call after permission grant.Check udapted code

Comment: @JasbinKarki hey sorry by mistake I have edit your code ...pleas add your original question again

Comment: @user2015187 thankyou for your valuable feedback again, i managed to fix permission :-) and now app is working

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.FLASHLIGHT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to add following permissions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Add the following to manifest. add in activity just ask for Camera
>   permission.

Read [enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html)

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
 <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.flash"
        android:required="false"/>
```